# Visible duration and actual duration of animation of shape along arc is different

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a very odd issue, trying to animate a triangle shape along a circular arc, from -π/2 to 2π-π/2 (to start from vertical position). Like this:

```
   // Construct the invisible animation path
   var path = UIBezierPath.FromArc(new PointF(rect.GetMidX(), rect.GetMidY()), (rect.Height - 20) / 2, (float)(- Math.PI / 2), (float)(2*Math.PI - Math.PI / 2), true);
   var pathLayer = new CAShapeLayer();
   pathLayer.Frame = rect;
   pathLayer.Path = path.CGPath;
   pathLayer.FillColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;
   pathLayer.StrokeColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;
   view.AddSublayer(pathLayer); // It appears that I need to create and add a layer to be able to animate along the path?

   // Create the shape to animate
   var triangleLayer = new CAShapeLayer();
   var triangle = CreateTriangle();
   triangleLayer.Frame = triangle.Bounds;
   triangleLayer.Path = triangle.CGPath;
   triangleLayer.StrokeColor = UIColor.Orange.CGColor;
   triangleLayer.FillColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;
   var triangleAnim = CAKeyFrameAnimation.GetFromKeyPath("position");
   triangleAnim.Path = path.CGPath;
   triangleAnim.Duration = 60;
   triangleAnim.RotationMode = CAKeyFrameAnimation.RotateModeAuto;
   triangleAnim.RemovedOnCompletion = false;

   triangleLayer.AddAnimation(triangleAnim, "progress");
   view.AddSublayer(triangleLayer);
```

The full round should take 60 seconds, but it finishes in about 45 seconds, then does nothing for 15 seconds, and then completes the animation. So the animation does seem to take 60 seconds, but the visual animation is only 45 seconds. The odd thing is that if I change the arc from 0 to 2π, the timing is correct. What could cause this issue?

The code is C# with Xamarin.iOS, but Objective C/Swift code would be similar.

Edit:

I found out that it works if I create a `UIBezierPath` arc from 0 - 2π and then rotate it with -π/2. So I suspect that there is something fishy going on with Xamarin.iOS and `UIBezierPath` with negative angles.

Comment: Why do you use `CAKeyFrameAnimation`?

Comment: That's the animation type that I could find that let me animate a layer along a defined path.

Comment: I don't see any keyframe animation in your code. If you don't use keyframes then you should resort to `CABasicAnimation` which animates from point A to B, from PathA to PathB, etc...

Comment: I don't see how I can use `CABasicAnimation` to animate a shape along a path. Can you give an example? I'm not trying to animate the path of the layer, but the position of the layer along a path.

Comment: Ah now I got it, you're right. Btw, angles are right too, I can't imagine why animation would go faster..

Answer (score 2):

I made a quick prototype app to test this. For simplicity, I used an image instead of a shape layer. Here is the outcome:

- Animating from `-M_PI_2` to `3 * M_PI_2` works as expected
- There is no need to add the invisible layer (just use the `path` you created)

This leads me to believe that perhaps your problem is buried in Xamarin.iOS. There have been some quirks with the `CGFloat` type, so maybe if you could cast the arguments explicitly somehow this might help.

Comment: Strange thing is, I have a different arc, which I animate with `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd`, with the same duration, and that animation follows the arc and duration perfectly.

Comment: And even stranger, setting the arc counter clockwise, with the same start and end angle, also have correct timing...

Comment: See my edit. Creating the arc from 0 - 2π and then rotate it by -π/2 yields correct results. So I'm suspecting something strange happens when there are negative angles in the arc.